# list the path of DIR command with a HASHTABLE

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell ,and I want to create a hash table that 
list the path of dir command and files found.  I've tried :

```
$hash1=@{label ="Files Found in ($_|select -first1).parent.fullname";Expression={$_.name}}
 dir c:\ |select-object -property $hash1
```

Expected output

### files Files Found in C:\

folder1
result3.html
file2.htm
file1.html
servers.txt

But I get this :

### Files Found in (|select -first1).parent.fullname

new
result3.html
result5.html
result55.html
servers.txt

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in a subexpressions if you want it to expand within the string. So change it to this:

```
$hash1=@{label ="Files Found in $(($_|select -first1).parent.fullname)";Expression={$_.name}}
```

**Edit:** Well then, looks like I should have tested that first. Seems that this may be a limitation of creating custom properties through `Select-Object`. What you could do instead is to pipe it through a ForEach loop and create `PSCustomObjects` for each item, which I have tested, and it does work:

```
dir c:\ |ForEach{[pscustomobject]@{"Files Found in $($_.parent.fullname)"=$_.name}}
```

Which results in:

```
Files Found in C:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
DRIVERS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Intel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PerfLogs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Program Files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Program Files (x86)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Temp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Users                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Windows
```

Comment: Thanks MadTechnician , but when i run this :

Comment: $hash1=@{label ="Files Found in $(($_|select -first 1).parent.fullname)";Expression={$_.name}}
 dir c:\ |select-object -property $hash1

Comment: i still get a  null object : Files Found in                                                                                                       
---------------                                                                                                      
1                                                                                                                    
12

Comment: I couldn't get your method to work, but did offer an alternative.